# Format DateInterval as ISO8601

Tags: php, datetime, iso8601, dateinterval

I am currently working on a php project and need to format a DateInterval as ISO8601 (something like this):

```
P5D
```

This format can be used to create DateTime and DateInterval objects, but I can't figure out a way to format a DateInterval into this format. Is there any? If not, what might be a lightweight solution to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you look at the spec for the format when you construct one:

> Y years
>
> M months
>
> D days
>
> W  weeks. These get converted into days, so can not be combined with D.
>
> H  hours
>
> M  minutes
>
> S  seconds

Then look at what you have to work with (http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php), it seems like what you would do is:

```
$dateInterval = new DateInterval( /* whatever */ );
$format = $dateInterval->format("P%yY%mM%dD%hH%iM%sS");
//P0Y0M5D0H0M0S
//now, we need to remove anything that is a zero, but make sure to not remove
//something like 10D or 20D
$format = str_replace(["M0S", "H0M", "D0H", "M0D", "Y0M", "P0Y"], ["M", "H", "D", "M", "Y0M", "P"], $format);
echo $format;
//P0M5D
```

Now, the one thing I did differently is I *always* include the months, even if it is 0.  The reason for this is that `minutes` and `months` are both represented by `M` - if we always include the month, then if there is a minute we know it is minutes.  Otherwise we have to do a bunch of logic to see if we need to change the `P` to `PT` so it knows that the a `M` in this instance stands for `Minute`.

For example:

```
// For 3 Months
new DateInterval("P3M");
// For 3 Minutes
new DateInterval("PT3M"));
```

But instead we do:

```
// For 3 Months
new DateInterval("P3M");
// For 3 Minutes
new DateInterval("P0M3M"));
```

Comment: Kinda sad PHP does not provide this functionality. Another function to fix bugs or missing features, yay!

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the [solution provided by Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33787489/1144627) and the [solution provided by Guss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42598056/1144627).

A workaround to add the `T` portion of the duration of the ISO 8601 standard and not need to default as `P0M`, is to insert 2 additional checks after the `P0Y` replaced by `Y`.

- `Y0M` replaced by `Y`
- `P0M` replaced by `P`
- change `D0H` to `TD0H` replaced by `DT`
- remove redundant `Y0M` replaced by `Y0M`

This works because the interval format will always generate the same structure, without leading 0's and `str_replace` walks through each replacement in the arrays from left to right.
As a result there is a possibility that we could receive `P1YT` or `PT` as a return value. Simply remove any trailing `PT` characters by using `rtrim`. Then substitute an empty value with a desired default value, as in the answer by Guss.

### ISO 8601 Assertions: https://3v4l.org/c55kL

*Compatible with PHP 5.3+*

*The use of the [static keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) is to improve performance of repeated calls to the function, as the static variables do not lose their values after leaving the function scope*

```php
function date_interval_iso(DateInterval $interval, $default = 'PT0S') {
    static $f = array('M0S', 'H0M', 'DT0H', 'M0D', 'P0Y', 'Y0M', 'P0M');
    static $r = array('M', 'H', 'DT', 'M', 'P', 'Y', 'P');

    return rtrim(str_replace($f, $r, $interval->format('P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS')), 'PT') ?: $default;
}
```

**Test**

To compare I created an array containing every possible duration combination (excluding microseconds) with a value of 1. Which can be viewed in the example link above.

```
$durations ['P1Y', /*...*/ 'P1Y1M1DT1H1M1S'];
$isos = array();
foreach ($durations as $duration) {
    $isos[] = date_interval_iso(new DateInterval($duration));
}

$diff = array_diff($durations, $isos);
if (!empty($diff)) {
    //output any differences
    var_dump($diff);
}

//test 0 duration DateInterval 
$date1 = new DateTime();
echo date_interval_iso($date1->diff($date1));
```

**Result**

```
PT0S
```

---

### PHP 7.1+ with Microseconds https://3v4l.org/VFN7N

You can add microseconds easily, by including `S0F` replaced by `S` of the first array values and adding `%fF` to your `DateInterval::format()`.

However `F` (microseconds) is not currently a supported interval specification for `DateInterval::__construct()` or the ISO 8601 standard.

> NOTE: there was a [bug in PHP <= 7.2.13 with `DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.14) that
> prevents the proper `DateInterval` retrieval when the difference was less than one second.

```
function date_interval_iso(DateInterval $interval, string $default = 'PT0F') {
    static $f = ['S0F', 'M0S', 'H0M', 'DT0H', 'M0D', 'P0Y', 'Y0M', 'P0M'];
    static $r = ['S', 'M', 'H', 'DT', 'M', 'P', 'Y', 'P'];

    return rtrim(str_replace($f, $r, $interval->format('P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS%fF')), 'PT') ?: $default;
}
```

**Test**

```
$date1 = new DateTimeImmutable();
$date2 = new DateTimeImmutable();

//test 0 duration DateInterval 
echo date_interval_iso($date1->diff($date1));

//test microseconds
echo date_interval_iso($date2->diff($date1));
```

**Result**

```
PT0F
PT21F
```

Answer (score 3):

With regards to @dave, I re-implemented his solution in a way that solves some of the problems, specifically the requirement to always leave a month field. From the [Wikipedia article on ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), it doesn't seem like the `T` designation is optional, even through its completely missing from the above mentioned implementation. By introducing it we can solve most of our problems and make for some cleaner code:

```
function date_interval_iso_format(DateInterval $interval) {
    list($date,$time) = explode("T",$interval->format("P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS"));
    // now, we need to remove anything that is a zero, but make sure to not remove
    // something like 10D or 20D
    $res =
        str_replace([ 'M0D', 'Y0M', 'P0Y' ], [ 'M', 'Y', 'P' ], $date) .
        rtrim(str_replace([ 'M0S', 'H0M', 'T0H'], [ 'M', 'H', 'T' ], "T$time"),"T");
    if ($res == 'P') // edge case - if we remove everything, DateInterval will hate us later
        return 'PT0S';
    return $res;
}
```

Note that we remove the T if it is not needed, so now both uses of `M` work fine:

```
"P5M" == date_interval_iso_format(new DateInterval("P5M")); // => true
"PT5M" == date_interval_iso_format(new DateInterval("PT5M")); // => true
```

Comment: I've updated the original code above to also handle the edge case of "zero interval" that the original code represented as `"P"` - which breaks the PHP `DateInterval` parser (that problem does not exist in @dave's implementation because he always leaves at least `0M`).